# invalid chars filter for file/folder name? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, filenames

My script downloads files from the net and then it saves them under the name taken from the same web server. I need a **filter**/remover of **invalid characters** for **file/folder names** under Windows NTFS.

I would be happy for multi platform filter too.

NOTE: something like `htmlentities` would be great....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Ruby string safe for a filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939333/how-to-make-a-ruby-string-safe-for-a-filesystem)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like Geo said, by using `gsub` you can easily convert all invalid characters to a valid character. For example:

```
file_names.map! do |f|
  f.gsub(/[<invalid characters>]/, '_')
end
```

You need to replace `<invalid characters>` with all the possible characters that your file names might have in them that are not allowed on your file system. In the above code each invalid character is replaced with a `_`.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) tells us that the following characters are not allowed on NTFS:

- U+0000 (NUL)
- / (slash)
- \ (backslash)
- : (colon)
- * (asterisk)
- ? (question mark)
- " (quote)
- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- | (pipe)

So your `gsub` call could be something like this:

```
file_names.map! { |f| f.gsub(/[\x00\/\\:\*\?\"<>\|]/, '_') }
```

which replaces all the invalid characters with an underscore.

Comment: @liwp: that is definitely a solution. I knew about gsub but was wondering if there was any gem and even cross platform available. Usually there few of them for anything ;-) Thank you for your code.

Answer (score 15):

```
filename_string.gsub(/[^\w\.]/, '_')
```

***Explanation:*** Replace everything except **word-characters** *(letter, number, underscore)* and **dots**

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be `gsub` on the filename. One of the things I know you'll need to delete/replace is `:`.

Comment: This isn't correct statement for Windows

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you plan to use those files later, but pretty much most reliable solution would be to keep the original filenames in a db table (or otherwise serialized hash), and name physical files after the unique ID that you (or the database) generated.

PS Another advantage of this approach is that you don't have to worry about the files with the same names (or different names that filter to same names).

Comment: I'm guessing humans would need to look at those files. Even if he removes the unwanted chars, the file's name could still mean something to someone, whereas an ID might not.

Comment: Ok, then. IDs are ok if you only plan to further serve these files through HTTP, for example.