# Regex negative lookbehind in Ruby doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby, regex, string, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

Making an argument parser. I want to split a string into an array where the delimiter is `", "` except when preceded by `"|"`. That means string

```
"foo, ba|, r, arg"
```

should result in

```
`["foo", "ba|, r", "arg"]`
```

I'm trying to use this regex: `(?<!\|),` which works in http://regexhero.net/tester/ but when I try

```
args.split(/(?<!\|), /)
```

in ruby, I get an error: `undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<!\|), /`

Comment: This works in 1.9 so if you can upgrade your Ruby installation, go ahead and do so.

Comment: @Michael Kohl that's exactly what I did :)

Comment: Also, for Ruby regex testing, I'd use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby's regex engine doesn't support lookbehind (yet).

You'd need to switch to 1.9 or use [Oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/).

---

If that's not an option, you can search for `|,` and replace it with some sort of marker. After all is said and done, put the `|,` back.

You can also try a regex like:

```
/(?:[^|]), /
```

But obviously the `(?:[^|])` is not zero-width, which means you'll need to do some extra work afterwards.

Comment: note that Ruby now supports negative lookbehind at least as of 1.9.3: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html