# Standardize a String for Filename, remove accents and special chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to find a way to normalize a string to pass it as a filename.

I have this so far:

```
my_string.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n, '').downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '_')
```

But first problem: the - character. I guess there is more problems with this method.

I don't control the name, **the name string can have accents, white spaces and special chars**. I want to remove all of them, replace the accents with the corresponding letter ('é' => 'e') and replace the rest with the '_' character.

The names are like:

- "Prélèvements - Routine"
- "Carnet de santé"
- ...

I want them to **be like a filename** with no space/special chars:

- "prelevements_routine"
- "carnet_de_sante"
- ...

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Ruby string safe for a filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939333/how-to-make-a-ruby-string-safe-for-a-filesystem)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at `ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate`, it's very useful handling this kind of chars problems. Read there: [`ActiveSupport::Inflector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate)

Then, you could do something like:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate my_string.downcase.gsub(/\s/,"_")
```

Comment: Does not work with names like "xxx l'amour". Fix: is to add gsub(/'/, '')

Comment: This also does not work with strings that contain other punctuation like comma ,

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `ActiveStorage::Filename#sanitized`, if spaces are okay.

If spaces are okay, which I would suggest keeping, if this is a User-provided and/or User-downloadable file, then you can make use of the `ActiveStorage::Filename#sanitized` method that is meant for exactly this situation.

It removes special characters that are not allowed in a file name, whilst keeping all of the nice characters that Users typically use to nicely organize and describe their files, like spaces and ampersands (&).

```rb
ActiveStorage::Filename.new( "Prélèvements - Routine" ).sanitized 
#=> "Prélèvements - Routine"

ActiveStorage::Filename.new( "Carnet de santé" ).sanitized 
#=> "Carnet de santé"

ActiveStorage::Filename.new( "Foo:Bar / Baz.jpg" ).sanitized 
#=> "Foo-Bar - Baz.jpg"
```

#### Use `String#parameterize`, if you want to remove nearly everything.

And if you're really looking to remove everything, try `String#parameterize`:

```rb
"Prélèvements - Routine".parameterize
#=> "prelevements-routine"

"Carnet de santé".parameterize
#=> "carnet-de-sante"

"Foo:Bar / Baz.jpg".parameterize
#=> "foo-bar-baz-jpg"
```